# All laravel output is prepended with letter "d" - why?

Tags: laravel

All laravel output is being prepended with the letter "d"

The result of running `php artisan --version` in CLI is `dLaravel Framework 7.3.0`

The first line of all HTML output: `d<!DOCTYPE html>`

I assume I did bad install or config but can't find it.  I have reinstalled laragon, but all my laragon files are in git so it is still showing up after cloning. Hoping there is an easy fix not obvious to me, or I suppose I'll have to reinstall.  Running on Laragon on Windows10.

Comment: You've likely mistakenly added a stray `d` character to the beginning of a file somewhere, which is then being output as plain text with every response.

Comment: check your web.php files or any PHP file that contains "d" before "<?php" 
Search it and delete that. Good luck...

Comment: What does your index.blade.php look like?

Comment: totally have a stray "d" but not finding it in the files mentioned..  @GautamPatadiya - that's a smart search query - but is not turning up.  Weird thing is that it's showing up in artisan commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you put d(letter) in somewhare like web.php(route file) or in somewhere in config file do check some file which is related run before any file and found the d

1 check web.php file first. 
2 middleware files.
3 config file.

Comment: Winner, winner.  The culprit was in \config\app.php.   Looks like my search is not working fully as it should have shown up.  Thanks for helping me pinpoint.